# Programmatically access activity of a specified Google Sheet

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

Google Sheets has a really useful [activity dashboard](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7573825?hl=en#:%7E:text=Drive%20and%20Docs.&text=Click%20Activity%20dashboard%20settings.,choose%20to%20hide%20their%20views.) that shows you who has accessed a given file, and when. I'd like to build a python script to enable me to enumerate these access logs, or any other type of access logs, for a list of ~100 Sheets.

I found [this article](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-drive), which I thought would help, but it only has guides to retrieve events for a domain, user, shared drive, or event type. I don't want to do this—I just want to supply a list of Sheet IDs (by which I mean the bits that come after the base URL in the link, so e.g. `ABCDEF` in `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ABCDEF`), and get the access logs back.

Would anybody be able to point me in the right direction, ideally with a python example? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to use the Directory API for this so can't work around following the steps on [this page](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-drive). You have to be an admin of the domain to be able to use the Reports API, though. Sheets and Drive APIs don't have this access.

Comment: Ah, damn, so if I'm just a user on the domain, the only way for me to see who has viewed my sheets is to open each sheet and view the activity dashboard manually? :(

Comment: From what I gather, this is unfortunately the case. Sheets API is only designed to be used as a Sheet *editor*, and the [Drive API Files resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) doesn't contain any information on this. I would suggest filing a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com) on Google's Issue Tracker.

Comment: That's a shame. Oh well, thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction, at least!! :)